# file output when using perl MIME::Parser

Tags: perl

How do I get the path for the below option?
basiclly  messages will be parsed to following dir "/tmp/msg-1370789006-11903-0" which is made up of
time and process ID , how do I get that into my varible for later use?

```
### Tell it where to put things:
    $parser->output_under("/tmp");
```

Comment: Do you mean you want `time` and `$$` which holds the UNIX timestamp and the current process id respectively?

Answer (score 0):

The distro's overall [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME-tools) (also found in the distro's `README` file) contains the following useful information:

```
 Overview of the classes

    Here are the classes you'll generally be dealing with directly:

        (START HERE)            results() .-----------------.
              \                 .-------->| MIME::          |
               .-----------.   /          | Parser::Results |
               | MIME::    |--'           `-----------------'
               | Parser    |--.           .-----------------.
               `-----------'   \ filer()  | MIME::          |
                  | parse()     `-------->| Parser::Filer   |
                  | gives you             `-----------------'
                  | a...                                  | output_path() 
                  |                                       | determines
                  |                                       | path() of...
                  |    head()       .--------.            |
                  |    returns...   | MIME:: | get()      |
                  V       .-------->| Head   | etc...     |
               .--------./          `--------'            |
         .---> | MIME:: |                                 |
         `-----| Entity |           .--------.            |
       parts() `--------'\          | MIME:: |           /
       returns            `-------->| Body   |<---------'
       sub-entities    bodyhandle() `--------'
       (if any)        returns...       | open()
                                        | returns...
                                        |
                                        V
                                    .--------. read()
                                    | IO::   | getline()
                                    | Handle | print()
                                    `--------' etc...
```

Which leads us to looking at MIME::Body's [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME%3a%3aBody), which include the following:

```
### Where's the data?
if (defined($body->path)) {   ### data is on disk:
    print "data is stored externally, in ", $body->path;
}
else {                        ### data is in core:
    print "data is already in core, and is...\n", $body->as_string;
}

### Get rid of anything on disk:
$body->purge;
```